# ghostscript renders shadow of single pixel

Tags: render, ghostscript, postscript, rasterizing

I'm having a problem rendering a PS document to TIFF (or any raster format). Single pixels have a "shadow" rendered one pixel below. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 10 10
<< /PageSize [10 10] >> setpagedevice
1 1 scale
/singlepx {
    newpath
    5 5 moveto
    0 1 rlineto
    1 0 rlineto
    0 -1 rlineto
    closepath
    setrgbcolor
    fill
} def
0.666 0.0 0.666 singlepx
```

Render command:

```
gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dFitPage -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
   -g10x10 -r600 -sDEVICE=tiffgray -sOutputFile=test.tif test.eps
```

The result is the same with the png and jpeg output devices.

[EPS rendered in evince](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aqxm.png)
[TIF produced by ghostscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKM12.png)

Answer (score 1):

You've set GraphicsAlphaBits=4, this does 'anti-aliasing. The result of that is that every drawn object extends further out by several pixels, these pixels are composed with the background.

If you look closely at the Evince output you'll see that there is considerably more than a 'single pixel' rendered. The rectangulsr shape has a border around 3 sides, 1 pixel wide. The colour is the colour of the rectangle, 50% composed with the background. At the corners, these are composed twice, with the result that you get 25% of the colour.

If you want to draw to the pixel level you can't use GraphicsAlphaBits.

Note that you are not drawing to a single 'pixel' anyway. Your rectangle is one PostScript unit wide by 1 unit high. PostScript's units are 1/72 inch. So at 72 dpi yes, its 1 pixel, but rendered at 1440 dpi that's 20 pixels by 20 pixels.

[edit]

Well, I think the problem here is that you are using incompatible command line switches and PostScript controls. Firstly your EPS file isn't valid, because it contains a setpagedevice, that's not legal for an EPS.

Your command line sets the resolution to 600 dpi, and the output size to 10x10 *pixels*. At 600 dpi that makes the media size 1/60 inch square. However, you also set -dFitPage. What that does is intercept MediaSize requests from the incoming data stream, figures out what scale factor is needed to make the requested media fit on the actual media, and then scales the content so that it fits on the actual media size.

Because your 'EPS' sets a media size, Ghostscript is executing some scaling to make the requested 10x10 unit square fit into a 10x10 pixel square. Now both the -g and the -dFitPage are executing scaling operations, and there is a limit to the accuracy with which this is performed.

Further complicating the problem is the fact that the PostScript rendering rule is 'any part of pixel', so if the scaling/accuracy should happen to work out in such a way that the mapping from  user space to device space doesn't **precisely** match the device space pixel grid, a pixel might be regarded as being (just barely) touched, and so will be rendered.

What is it you are actually trying to achieve ? It might be easier to address that than try to fix what you are currently doing.

Note that PostScript (unlike some other PDLs) doesn't let you address the device pixels at all, and you are (if I remember correctly) explicitly told that you can't reliably do so, either in the PLRM or one of the supporting books.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I should have stated that the included images were screenshots at 2000% in order to (try to!) clearly illustrate the issue. The problem is if anything worse if I use GraphicsAlphaBits=1. Then ghostscript renders two pixels in full colour. But your point about PostScript units is good, maybe I can use that to convince ghostscript to render it correctly.

Comment: Don't set GraphcisAlphaBits=1, don't set it **at all**.

Comment: Thanks again @KenS, but I'm afraid that doesn't work. With GraphicsAlphaBits either omitted or unset (with `-u`) a solid 1x2 pixel rectangle is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your time @KenS. Of course changing/fixing the EPS file is possible. I have tried removing the setpagedevice line but there is no change. I am simply trying to get gs to render a 1px square without turning it into a rectangle! This is obviously a minimal example and the final use will have many such pixels on a much larger canvas. This command line `gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -g10x10 -sDEVICE=tiffgray -sOutputFile=test.tif test.eps` still produces the incorrect result.

Comment: OK, I have found a solution. If I use `rectfill` instead of filling a path then it works correctly. See [here](https://pastebin.com/6cMjrvjZ).

Comment: As I said previously, you aren't supposed to try to address device pixels directly in PostScript, fundamentally that won't work. If you want to scatter pixels around you might be better off with an image (or imagemask) instead. The rules for images are different, pixel centres rather than any part of pixel.